# Why is my p-table populating twice while looping a 2D array

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I think each table is being populated the size of the test array. Is there a way to only populate each table once on the correct table index?

In the .ts file I have headers and my 2D string array

```
headers = ['Header1', 'Header2']
test = [['Test1', 'Test2'], ['Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5']]
```

My HTML looks like this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let h of headers; let i = index"
   <h2>{{ h }}</h2>
   <p-table>
      <ng-template p template="body">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let rows of test[i]; let j = index">
            <label>{{rows}}</label>
         </ng-container>
      </ng-template>
   </p-table>
</ng-container>
```

When I do this my table looks like this:

Header1

| Table1 |
| --- |
| Test1 |
| Test2 |
| Test1 |
| Test2 |

Header2

| Table2 |
| --- |
| Test3 |
| Test4 |
| Test5 |
| Test3 |
| Test4 |
| Test5 |

when I want it to display like this:

| Table1 |
| --- |
| Test1 |
| Test2 |

| Table2 |
| --- |
| Test3 |
| Test4 |
| Test5 |

Comment: your loop looking good, [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6aapx9?file=src/main.ts). So I think the problem is the `p-table` component

Comment: I want to use p-table though because there is a global style I want to reuse

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using loop in a wrong way, Can yu please use this way.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let h of headers; let i = index">
   <h2>{{ h }}</h2>
   <p-table>
      <ng-template p template="body">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let row of test[i]; let j = index">
            <tr>
               <td>{{ row }}</td>
            </tr>
         </ng-container>
      </ng-template>
   </p-table>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PrimeNG tables, you need to use their syntax:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let h of headers; let i = index">
  <p-table [value]="test[i]" responsiveLayout="scroll">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>{{ headers[i] }}</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-item>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</ng-container>
```

[StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-2uc6fh?file=src/app/app.component.html)